# Java - Can I use JarURLConnection to execute jar classes?

Tags: java

I'm running on an environment with the "jar://" uri scheme supported, and I want to use JarURLConnection to invoke any function within that jar. example:

```
jar:file:/home/duke/duke.jar!/COM/foo/Main.class
```

oracle docs say:

> JarURLConnection instances can only be used to read from JAR files. It is not possible to get a OutputStream to modify or write to the underlying JAR file using this class.

My question is: Can I somehow **run** a code using the `jar://` scheme alone? or only read class contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t use JarURLConnection directly for this.  Instead, you create a [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and use it to obtain the relevant class:

```
    Path jar = Paths.get("/home/duke/duke.jar");

    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(
            new URL[] { jar.toUri().toURL() });

        Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName("com.foo.Main", true, classLoader);
        mainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, new String[0]);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException | MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not run " + jar, e);
    }
```

URLClassLoader uses JarURLConnection internally, but you don’t need to use it directly.

Comment: Thanks so much. i understand the answer is that its not possible to use jar:// scheme to run jar file main functions?

Comment: Correct.  While in theory you could refer to a jar inside a jar using a jar: URL, it would be pretty inefficient.  (I believe the Java EE reference implementation used to do that with .ear files, and the performance was so poor, they had to find another way.)